# Return sequence of characters if compose fails

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to create a Linux "port" for the Windows Russian phonetic keyboard and I have:

<kbd>я</kbd> <kbd>э</kbd> <kbd>ё</kbd> <kbd>ю</kbd> set as <kbd>j</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> as on Windows.

I added lines like

`<Cyrillic_shorti> <Cyrillic_o> : "ё"`

for example. But when I type short

<kbd>I</kbd> + anything else

it doesn't work. How can I have it return the short I it failed to match?